# Xslt format-number from xml input

Tags: xml, xslt, decimalformat

I have an input xml file

```
<elementOne>
  <elementTwo>
   <RequestItem>
    <elementThree>
      <value>314.4</value>
    </elementThree>
   </RequestItem>
  </elementTwo>
 </elementOne>
```

and the xslt bellow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
<xsl:decimal-format name="euro" decimal-separator="." grouping-separator=","/>
<xsl:template match="/*">

    <Value>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(/elementOne/elementTwo/RequestItem/elementThree/value/text()),'##,00')"/>
    </Value>

</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have tried many ways based on what I found on internet but I did not 
manage the output to be 314,40

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you want the decimal separator to be a comma, you must define it as such:

```
<xsl:decimal-format name="euro" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="."/>
```

Then, if you have defined a decimal format, you must also tell the stylesheet to use it:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(/elementOne/elementTwo/RequestItem/elementThree/value), '#,00', 'euro')"/>
```

Or, if you also want the defined thousands separator to be applied:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(/elementOne/elementTwo/RequestItem/elementThree/value), '#.###,00', 'euro')"/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I only add the  extra zero in the format to represent the decimals correct ('#0,00')

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Use `'#,00'` if you want to show two decimals. Use `'0,00'`if you also want amounts less than 1 to be displayed with 0 as the units - e.g. `.5` --> `"0,50"`.